# __eq__ method to compare two custom objects with list

Tags: python, equality, python-dataclasses, equality-operator

I have a python class that contains a list of strings. I want to compare two instances of this class. However, I noticed that if my class gets large the comparison gets quite cumbersome to write. Is there an easier way to write the `__eq__` method than this? I use a List instead of a Set because I want to fill this class with data from JSON at a later stage.

```py
json_one = {"var_one": "hello", "var_two": ["foo", "bar"]}
json_two = {"var_one": "hello", "var_two": ["bar", "foo"]}

@dataclass
class Test:
    var_one: str
    var_two: List[str]

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Test):
            return self.var_one == other.var_one\
                   and sorted(self.var_two) == sorted(other.var_two)
        return False


test_one = Test(**json_one)
test_two = Test(**json_two)

if test_one == test_two:
    print("yay we're equal with lists in different order")
```

Comment: Not really. A dataclass can generate the method if it's just an equality comparison of attributes, if you want something more complex than that it's down to you. If `var_two`'s order doesn't matter, maybe a set would be more appropriate?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what exactly is supposed to be "cumbersome" here. Looks quite straight forward and compact to me. I don't understand what you want to have simplified here. There is no need for more simplification. ---- There is only one thing you should change: As apparently order is not important you should use a set for your `var_two`, not a regular list.

Comment: @RegisMay well image a class with 20 variables. that will be one big if statement. the reason for List is that i get data from JSON and in that JSON data there are lists.

Comment: Deal with that at the "edge" of your system, where the data comes in or goes out - you shouldn't have everything else held hostage to that limitation of JSON.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i've updated the code example, that's how i want to work where i can just get JSON from some API expand it into a python object and then manipulate that object.

Comment: The point is _don't_ just expand the JSON into a Python object if the default structure doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: Define your class *independent* of JSON, and add a (class) method that can specifically parse JSON to create an instance of the class.

Comment: yeah but don't i just move the problem then? If i don't expand it, i will need a method that creates the class according to my needs. it feels pretty equal to just making that really long eq method.

Comment: You are only using a list because JSON itself doesn't encode sets. That doesn't mean your class should avoid the use of a set, but rather *create* the set you want from the JSON object. The definition of `__eq__` you want will follow from that action.

Comment: so you mean something like this?
    @staticmethod
    def parse_json(**kwargs):
        return Test(var_one = kwargs["var_one"], var_two = set(kwargs["var_two"]))

Comment: More or less (though I would prefer a class method; see my answer).

Comment: @Kinder9211 Yes, for a class with 20 variables it will take some lines of code to implement the comparison. Initialization of 20 variables will take quite some lines of code as well. It is quite normal that things scale linear with the amount of variables. That's normal.

Comment: @Kinder9211 Regarding your lists: It is irrelevant if your class receives data from JSON. If the in-memory data model - implemented by your class - treats this data as a set, you should use a set. Typically you should avoid aligning your in-memory data model with aspect of external storage. Focus on data processing rather than specific ways of storage. if you violate this principle you should really know what you are doing (because then you should have a good reason).

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you *can* define an instance of your class using the output of `json.load` should not dictate your class's design. Rather, define your class "naturally", and provide a method for using a JSON response to create the instance.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import json

@dataclass
class Test:
    # Emphasize the independence of your class from any particular JSON object
    str1: str
    set_of_str1: set[str]

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, s):
        d = json.loads(s)
        return cls(d['var_one'], set(d['var_two']))


assert Test("foo", set(["bar", "baz"])) == \
        Test.from_json('{"var_one": "foo", "var_two": ["baz", "bar"]}')
```